# Azure AD B2C and regular (SQL) Identity .Net6

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, azure-ad-b2c

Just have general question if it possible to use Azure AD B2C to LogIn to the project and inside project manage Identity Users ? The problem is we have internal (company workers) in Azure AD and external users (customers) in SQL Identity tables like AspNetUsers,AspNetRoles...I created new project and point to it Azure AD B2C it works to LogIn/LogOut but as soon as I scaffold Identity it replace login Page (Windows Login Page) with own Identity Page and want user to logIn as regular Identity user. The goal is to create users management inside this app login to which is with Azure AD B2C. Sorry no any code here , is general question is it possible at all?
Thnks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So you want to log in with Azure B2C and manage users in an external DB?

You would have to create "shadow" users in B2C, store the minimum attributes and then use a REST API to get the rest from SQL.

You would need some attribute to map a B2C user to a SQL user.

And keep the users in synch.

Also, the password would have to live in B2C.

Why don't you just [migrate](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples#user-migration) the users?

You could migrate the user details (first name, surname etc.) and leave the complex role structure in SQL and access it via REST API. You could then [add those roles](https://mrochon.azurewebsites.net/2019/05/06/using-groups-in-azure-ad-b2c/) to the JWT returned to the user.

Comment: Thank you for advise , Company don't want to migrate because they want to separate customers from workers and keep them in different places and they afraid that some legacy code (WebForms) can has issue with changing logic in app and so....

Comment: I was thinking to add in SQL some user like "SuperAdmin" and after login with B2C programmatically SignIN with preset credentials not sure if it good idea....like if you Authenticated with B2C it means you are "SuperAdmin"